# I can't setup a monero pool on current software

Tags: mining-pools, development

I know this is the wrong place, but I need help setting up a pool with the current versions of node.js and the other requirements. Every reference I found is 3 - 4 years old and github code years old or the maintainer says to follow the readme.  How would I create a pool from scratch?  For example, you need to know how to code in node.js, Ajax, HTML, and bash. These are the functions you will need to code to setup a node.js pool. 
Unless someone knows of a pool that is using node.js 8.x and is willing to share the code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Snipa's [nodejs-pool](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool). It runs on NodeJS 8+ if I remember correctly and has auto-deployment script which does most of the work during setting up phase... Also, refer to [repository's issues](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool/issues) for further questions, I think you will get an answer there faster than here.